# If two objects have the same drag coefficient, but one is much heavier, would it fall faster?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, projectile, drag

Not sure this is a good example but imagine we have two feathers, both with exactly the same drag coefficient, they have the exact same shape and everything, but the only difference is that one of them is somehow much more heavier (let's say it's much more dense), would their terminal velocities be different?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the lighter object falling with a terminal speed.
Whilst this is happening the drag force upwards is equal to the weight of the lighter object downwards.

Now consider the heavier object travelling at the same speed as the lighter object's terminal speed.
The drag force upwards is the same whilst the weight of the heavier object is greater than the weight of the lighter object and hence the drag force.
So the heavier object must accelerate downwards eventually reaching a higher terminal speed than the lighter object.

Answer (score 1):

All other things being equal, the drag force is proportional to drag coefficient times velocity squared*. When an object is heavier, the force of gravity is greater. Since terminal velocity is reached when drag force equals force of gravity, that will happen at a higher velocity for the heavier object.

So "yes".

---

<sup>* Really the drag force is given by $$F_d=\frac12\rho v^2 A C_D$$
Where $\rho$ is the density of the fluid (same for both feathers), $v$ is the velocity, $A$ the projected area (same), and $C_D$ the drag coefficient (same for the same shape at the same velocity, varies very slowly with velocity). The velocity term is the only one that is potentially different between the two feathers.</sup>

Comment: This is incorrect because you don't account for the effect of the density in the drag.

Comment: @Kimusubi  clarified my answer. The density in the equation is density of the medium (air) which does not change between the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

Heavier object will have greater force of gravity; due to this simple fact the object with heavier mass will attain terminal velocity at greater speed than the lighter one. I hope this answers your question